# Autocomplete doesn't $.empty/comeback when $.removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete on an input and next to it is a select element.
When I trigger the `$.autocomplete` once it creates an HTML list `<lu ..><li ..></li></lu>` if I then select a new option I don't want it to autocomplete anymore until I switch back.

I can remove the element with an `$.remove` but then it doesn't come back if I trigger the autocomplete event again.
I can't `$.empty` it for some reason.

```js
var array = ['this', 'that', 'bla', 'potato'];

$('.input').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('.option').val() === 'this') {
    $('.input').autocomplete({
      source: array
    });
  } else {
    // Something that removes/deactivates the autocomplete.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='options'>
  <option value='this'>DoAutocomplete</option>
  <option value='that'>DoNotAutocomplete</option>
<select>

<input class='input' />
```

**Does anybody have an Idea how I can solve this?**

Comment: Your code snipplet doesn't seem to function.  I don't get autocomplete in any case.  Also did you checkout the api for autocomplete?  I mean a quick search and I found http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-disable

Comment: Completely scrolled past this, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking this might be easier to just detect what the value of the selected option is in the dropdown and use Taplars comment on your question to enable or disable the autocomplete based on the selected value.  I didn't try your code, but I think the 'keyup' detection was part of the issue.

Here is an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gugktm7u/1/)

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array = ['this', 'that', 'bla', 'potato'];

  $('#input').autocomplete({
            source: array
  });

  $('#select').on('change', function (e) {
        var selection = $("#select option:selected").val();

        if (selection == 'off') {
                $( "#input" ).autocomplete("disable");
        } else {
                $( "#input" ).autocomplete("enable");
        }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
Toggle Autocomplete:
<select id='select'>
  <option value='on'>On</option>
  <option value='off'>Off</option>
</select><br><br>

<input id='input'>
```